# need to provide timeout for error handling using c

Tags: c

I am developing a code to make communicate between two controller boards. I am passing 9 byte message from one board to another. Need to define error handling on receiver side such that it will wait for 9 byte value until timeout occurs. If timeout is reached, control should start from the 1st line of function.

currently I have defined one line like

```
while (/*wait_loop_cnt++<= MAX_WAIT_LOOP &&*/ counter < length);
```

in my code but it will remain in the same loop infinitely if doesn't receive 9 byte.

Please help thank you

Comment: How is the message sent between boards?

Comment: Check the time each iteration OR use select/poll with a timeout if you're using sockets OR set a timer interrupt. Any of those would work.

Comment: @Taegyung   I am using RS485 protocol to communicate between boards. "length" is 9 bytes which are message bytes. inside counter I am calculating received number of bytes. By using while loop I am waiting for counter to be reached at 9 but if some errors occurs and board will not received 9 bytes, it will be remained in the same loop. I have tried using below code 
  while (/*wait_loop_cnt++<= MAX_WAIT_LOOP &&*/ counter < length);
  {
    if (MAX_WAIT_LOOP < 200) 
     break;
  }             but it is showing me error ""break" may only be used within a loop or switch" please guide.

Comment: How is `wait_loop_cnt` defined and even more important how is it initialised  before entering the loop?

Comment: Is this trailing  `;` by intention? As it stands your while has not have a body. Any `{}` after it is *not* part of it.

Comment: Ok, stopping to guess. Please show all relevant code.

Comment: @alk not using wait_loop_cnt      i am using while(counter<length){if(MAX_WAIT_LOOP < 200){break;}} it is giving me error as  ""break" may only be used within a loop or switch" is there any other way to implement the same?

Comment: Nobody will be able to reproduce this with the information given. You'll have to add much more code, tell what system that you use and a spec of the protocol used.

Comment: Tell us how do you read/write bytes from the boards. If it is a simple read/write from some device then *select* function is your friend here. It does all you need: it waits until the data arrives (is sent) to the device or an error has occured or the time is up. If you use port io then possibly nothing better than delays can be suggested.

Comment: "*it is giving me error as ""break" may only be used within a loop*" so you are not using the `break` statement inside a loop. `while(condition){ if (another_condtion) { break; }}` is valid. Mind the semicolon, as used here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339592/need-to-provide-timeout-for-error-handling-using-c/55340346#comment97405248_55339592 `while(condition);{ if (another_condtion) { break; }}` is ***not*** valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const int length = 9;
int counter = 0;
int wait_loop_cnt = 0;

while (
  wait_loop_cnt++ <= MAX_WAIT_LOOP && 
  counter < length) /* NO semicolon here! */
{
  if (read_byte_successfully(...))
  {
    ++counter;
  }
}

if (counter < length) 
{
  /* Handle case of to few bytes received here. */
}
```